# How do I move a div with class of `box` using slide animation on hover effect?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a div (with class of `box`) that already has some transitions applied to it, plus want to add slide animation on hover effect on the same div?

```
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  transition-property: background, color;
  transition-duration: .2s, 4s;
  transition-timing-function: linear, ease-out;
  transition-delay: 2s, ;
 }


@keyframes slide{
    0% {
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
    }
    50% {
     left: 244px;
     top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
     left: 488px;
     top: 0;
    }
 }



.box:hover .box{
  background-color: yellow;
  color:white;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

html:

```
 <div class="box"> </div>
```

Comment: `.box:hover .box` ? --> why not `.box:hover`

Comment: Yea, this looks like a Typo. What @TemaniAfif said seems to be logical.

Comment: I'm still new and learning. .box:hover .box doesn't work  I know.... :-(

Comment: simply  read your selector and you will understand why it's not working

Comment: `.box:hover .box ` was used because I want animation and transition to happen together on hover.

Comment: as i said, you simply need `.box:hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added absolute position  .box{position:absolute} to .box class and change .box:hover .box to .box:hover. Hope this help

```css
       
     

.box {
          position: absolute;
          background-color: red;
          width: 70px;
          height: 70px;
          transition-property: background, color;
          transition-duration: .2s, 4s;
          transition-timing-function: linear, ease-out;
          transition-delay: 2s, ;
         }
        
        
        @keyframes slide{
            0% {
             left: 0;
             top: 0;
            }
            50% {
             left: 244px;
             top: 100px;
            }
            100% {
             left: 488px;
             top: 0;
            }
         }
        
        
        
        .box:hover{
          background-color: yellow;
          color:white;
          animation-name: slide;
          animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-delay: .5s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }
```

```html
 
        <div class="box"> </div>
```

Comment: :-) This is so awesome! Thank You.